# How to delegate JsonObjectRequests from abstract android class to a handler properly

Tags: android, callback, singleton, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I am currently working on an android project, in which I use Volley to handle some JsonObjectRequests.

The requesting components are all stored in an abstract fragment class, so that all fragments inheriting from it are able so send requests to my API and handle the response in a customizable way.

The overall class:

```
public abstract class RequestingFragment extends Fragment implements RequestCallbacks {

    public RequestQueue requestQueue;

    public final void startRequest(final RequestOperation operation) {

        String url = getContext() != null ? getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.base_url) : "";

        final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, baseUrl + operation.url(requestParams), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                onSuccess(response, operation.parsingKey());
                onFinished(operation.parsingKey());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                onError(operation.parsingKey());
                onFinished(operation.parsingKey());
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    //these are intended to be defined in the subclasses
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject json, String parsingKey) {

    }

    public void onError(String parsingKey) {

    }

    public void onFinished(String parsingKey) {

    }

}
```

Now during further development I'am facing the problem that not only fragments have to be able to send requests, but also components, like a RecyclerView.Adapter or a BroadcastReceiver. So I planned to migrate the request functionality to a handler singleton following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue) description.

As in the code snippet above you can see, that those callbacks take parameters from the request response, so I'm wondering if it is a better approach, to just return the result of the request (which can be different objects like JSONObject or VollerError), or to pass the callback to `startRequest()` as a Runnable like written in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222070/how-to-pass-a-function-as-an-parameter-to-another-function).

**EDIT**

I tried out the second approach and the `startRequest` of the RequestHandler now looks like this:

```
public void startRequest(RequestOperation operation, final Runnable onSuccess, final Runnable onError, final Runnable onFinished) {

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, instance_context.getResources().getString(R.string.base_url), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            onSuccess.run();
            onFinished.run();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            onError.run();
            onFinished.run();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Now my question is: I have read that a `Runnable` executes on an own thread per default. In the [Volley docs](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple) it says, that the response of the RequestQueue is delivered to the main thread. Now some of my responses are used to update my UI so if I do that inside the callbacks, isn't that async then? Do I have to reload my UI at the end of the callback?

**EDIT 2**

I'm trying to subclass Runnable, so that I can pass parameters to the `run()`method. Then I'll try testing on how the UI updating performs.

Comment: onResponse(), gets called on Main thread

Comment: yes, but inside onResponse() i will call onSuccess.run(), and that executes on a side thread.

Comment: onResponse() : executes your tasks on worker and once done, the result gets executed with runOnUiThread (main thread)

Comment: ok, i'll try that out, once i'm done subclassing runnable, so I can pass params

Comment: you don't need runOnUiThread inside onResponse(), it works explicitely

Comment: i understood ;)

Comment: alright, just another FYI, if you have a huge list to load, better use  Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) and onDeliverResult

Comment: they're very small to moderate size